# How to center image over 2 columns in bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I want to create a split screen Bootstrap 4 page and put an image in the center overlapping the two columns. I have created two equal columns but I have no idea how to place the image to overlap them.

I have tried `position:absolute` and `float:left` but it doesn't help. Thank you for your help!

Expected:
[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n52Sg.jpg)

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

col {
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://imgur.com/Qk5Qa9M.jpg" class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:auto">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col" style="background-color:blue">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:red">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: I posted an answer, did you read it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this is solving your problem:

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

col {
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0; /* i deleted top:0; */
  left: 50%; /* this and below code for excellent centered */
  transform:translateX(-50%);
  z-index:2;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/400/500">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col" style="background-color:blue">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:red">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

also, i deleted `class` and `style` attribute from `img` tag. because they unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

Add `z-index: 1;` in your `img` css

```
img {
  z-index: 1;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the solution provided by Dogukan Cayus.

Answer (score 0):

add simply `z-index` to in your img class

The z-index property specifies the stack order of an element. An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order.

**Note: z-index only works on positioned elements (position:absolute, position:relative, or position:fixed)**

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: hidden;
}

col {
  height: 100vh;
}

img {
  position: absolute;
  top: 15%;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1001;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Website</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://imgur.com/Qk5Qa9M.jpg" class="mx-auto d-block" style="width:auto">
  <div class="row h-100">
    <div class="col" style="background-color:blue">
      Left
    </div>
    <div class="col" style="background-color:red">
      Right
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thank you. I used the solution provided by Dogukan Cayus.

Comment: no problem at all, but you want to choose first answer, ok!!